# Bulk update all references between two collections in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections, raw_doc and unique_doc in Mongo.
raw_doc receives imports of a large amount of data on a regular basis ( +500k rows ).  unique_doc has every unique instance of 3 fields found in raw_doc.

A shortened example of the data in each table

**raw_doc**

```
{Licence : "Free", Publisher : "Jeff's music", Name: "Music for all",Customer:"Dave", uniqueclip_id:12345},
{Licence : "Free", Publisher : "Jeff's music", Name: "Music for all",Customer:"Jim", uniqueclip_id:12345}
```

**unique_doc**

```
{_id:12345, Licence : "Free", Publisher : "Jeff's music", Name: "Music for all"}
```

I would like to add a reference to raw_doc, linking it to the appropriate unique_doc.  I can't use the three fields in unique_doc for the key as those fields will be edited eventually, but the data in raw_doc will stay the same(thus the data will no longer match but still needs to be linked).

Is there a query I could run in Mongo that would pull in bulk the IDs from unique_doc and insert them into the appropriate raw_docs?

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate a bit more your question? As I could understand you want to put references (why not an id?) to the raw_doc in the unique doc, but something will change over time.

Comment: The id is exactly what I want, but currently I can only see a way to add the ids one by one, I would like to have a single query that updates all of the ids (as is possible with SQL).  My current testing shows that one by one the process takes several hours.  That's a weeee bit too long for my liking.

Comment: Is it like, "License in _id:12345 has changed", update all the raw_doc that has this id?

Comment: Nope, so the two collections get created at the same time.  At that point the rows in raw_doc need to be linked to the rows in unique_doc.  The problem is how time consuming it is to link the ids from unique_doc to raw_doc one by one.  I'm after a query the basically says "if unique_doc matches raw_doc add unique_doc id to raw_doc".

Comment: I suspect my best option is to generate the id myself before inserting the data, that way I don't need to do any updates.

Comment: I believe you have two options here: 1 - Generate the id yourself and insert it to each raw_doc. 2 - Use the UpdateMany function. If you choose number two, I can post a code in the answer

Comment: I'm keen to see your update many code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating my own id up front seems to be the way to go.  I have managed to keep the processing time down to around 120s for 500k rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `updateMany`. Please try this:

```
db.raw_doc.updateMany({uniqueclip_id:"12345"},{$set:{uniqueclip_id:"54321"}})
```

This will update all the documents in raw_doc that contains the uniqueclip_id:"12345" and will set it to "54321".

Comment: that's essentially what I'm doing now that is taking too long (hours).  I'll test generating my own id and see what happens.

Comment: Then I don't know.